# In OS X, how to get the window frame size correctly?

Tags: swift, macos

I try to create an OS X window programmatically as below:

```
print("creating window frame=\(winFrame)")

let window = NSWindow(contentRect: winFrame, styleMask: [NSWindowStyleMask.resizable, NSWindowStyleMask.closable, NSWindowStyleMask.miniaturizable, NSWindowStyleMask.titled], backing: NSBackingStoreType.buffered, defer: false)

print("after window frame=\(window.frame)")
```

I was expecting these two output should be the same, however here is the output

```
creating window frame=(1556.0, 193.0, 421.0, 646.0)
after window frame=(1556.0, 193.0, 421.0, 668.0)
```

The difference is that the height is increased from 646 to 668.

Why is there such a difference and how to get the right number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The window's `contentRect` is the rect, in global screen coordinates, to be occupied by the `contentView` of the window. This rect **does not include** the window's title bar. The window's `frame` **does include** the title bar.

If you have a desired window frame, you can compute the corresponding content rect, then use the content rect to create the window:

```
let winFrame = ...
let styleMask: NSWindowStyleMask = [.resizable, .closable, .miniaturizable, .titled]
let contentRect = NSWindow.contentRect(forFrameRect: winFrame, styleMask: styleMask)
let window = NSWindow(contentRect: contentRect, styleMask: styleMask, backing: .buffered, defer: false)
```

Or you can just set the window's frame after you create it, like this:

```
let winFrame = ...
let styleMask: NSWindowStyleMask = [.resizable, .closable, .miniaturizable, .titled]
let window = NSWindow(contentRect: .zero, styleMask: styleMask, backing: .buffered, defer: false)
window.setFrame(winFrame, display: true)
```

Comment: Thanks! Both solutions are great! For now I chose the second solution.

Answer (score 1):

While creating the `NSWindow` you set the `contentRect` which is **not** the frame.

> An NSWindow object is defined by a frame rectangle that encloses the entire window, including its title bar, border, and other peripheral elements (such as the resize control), and by a content rectangle that encloses just its content area.

-- From the [How Windows Work](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/WinPanel/Concepts/HowWindowsWork.html) page out of the Window Programming Guide

So you are getting the correct frame size of the window. Either you want to create a smaller one by passing in a smaller `contentRect` or you want to access the `contentView.frame` property.